# Inner join in QGIS 3.22.7

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have to join some attributes of two layers in QGIS (3.22.7). Therefore, I am required to use inner join. When I go to the layer properties of the first layer and join the two layers/tables with a common attribute, then the resultant table had null values which should not be present. For that, I have filtered the null values of that column of the second layer before applying the join. Still, the final table has the null values. Hence, I think the join I am doing is the left join and inner join could be a solution to avoid null values in that column. So, how can I apply inner join in QGIS 3.22.7?

I have to use the following SQL query

```
SELECT A.ATT1, A.ATT2, B.BTT1
FROM LAYER1 B
INNER JOIN LAYER2 A
ON A.ATT1 = B.BTT2
WHERE B.BTT2 NOT LIKE 'NULL' and B.BTT2 LIKE 'ABC'
```

I have tried to filter the NULL values with the following command
"BTT2" NOT LIKE 'NULL' and "BTT2" LIKE 'ABC'
The output is
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton, thanks for the response. I have now edited my question with some details. Hope it will clarify my problem. Thanks.

Comment: please show us the SQL you are using and some example output

Comment: I have added SQL and sample output of the problem

Comment: `WHERE B.BTT2 IS NOT NULL AND B.BTT2 = 'ABC'` is the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) with the query:

```
select t1.*
from layername1 t1
inner join layername2 t2
on t1.fieldx = t2.fieldy
```